# Isolating Custom dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I built a custom dropdown that replaces the old school `<select>` dropdown. As you know, these ugly things are controlled by the browser and since the site is predominantly dark, I don't want a white dropdown box like the one that comes with the `<select>` element.

I used the following JS:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function (e) {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            //event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click', function () {
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex: function () {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(function () {

    var dd = new DropDown($('.custom-dropdown'));
    //var dd = new DropDown($('#dd2'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
        // dropdown closes by clicking outside
        $(".custom-dropdown ul").parent().removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Select Your Area</label>
    <div id="dd" class="custom-dropdown form-control">
        <span>Select One</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">White/Caucasian</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Black/African-American</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hispanic</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Asian</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pacific Islander</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Middle-Eastern</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do the following:

```
var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));
var dd = new DropDown($('#dd2'));

...

var dd = new DropDown($('#ddnth'));
```

the problem is solved. In fact, it is what I've been doing. But this is rather cumbersome. This application will have about 1000 data entry pages. Therefore this is less than ideal.

My JS shows `var dd = new DropDown($('.custom-dropdown'));` Which fixes the initializing issue because a class can be shared, an ID can not, BUT...when I pick an option from one of the dropdowns, it populates all of them (because of the class, I know) :(

So, help me out here. How can I initialize this globally and isolate the dropdowns population to just the one being used?

See my DEMO [**here**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/LNNVYv) p.s. I apologize for the SCSS, click on view compiled if that helps you. Even thought this is not a CSS question anyhow ;)

Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping it on every same class instead.

E.g.

```
    $('.custom-dropdown').each(function (index, value)  {
        var dd = new DropDown($(value));
    });
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqqPRv)**

Comment: I knew it had to be an easy solution for you guys. You rock buddy. Obrigado e abracos!

Comment: @LOTUSMS Great! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the initiator as `var dd = new DropDown($('.custom-dropdown'));` but if `$('.custom-dropdown')` is multiple elements, then what is dd refering to?

If I added a prototype function like dd.setValue("value"), it would only make sense that all the dropdowns in dd would be set to "value".  dd should only represent one dropdown.  It doesn't make much sense that dd is multiple different dropdowns if you get what I'm trying to say.

Either you could rewrite it to work as:

```
$('.custom-dropdown').createDropDown();
$('.custom-dropdown').eq(0).getDropDownValue();
```

or you could have each single dropdown in an array:

```
var dds=[];
$('.custom-dropdown').each(function(){
    dds.push(new DropDown($(this)));
});

dds[2].getValue();
```

Comment: +1 for a great explanation and advise. Good job. I originally got this code form a codepen that was done by someone else and it worked for me with minor modifications. This one being the one I couldn't crack. But your explanation is on point